# Python win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2 () failed to mount, network paths which contain non-ascii characters

Tags: python, unicode

I am facing a problem with network paths which contain non-ascii
characters when trying to map them.

More precisely, the location contains unicode characters.
location = '\\192.10.12.122\युनिक'

WNetAddConnection2 function expects string type as remoteName argument.

A simple call certainly fails:

```
win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(
        win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
        None, location, None,
        None, None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\eclipseworkspaces\training\pytraining\win32networkstuff\unc.py",
line 66, in ?
    None, None)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
30-44: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I couldn't figure out the right encoding for the UNICODE string. I tried both
'utf8' and 'mbcs' encodings, something like:

```
win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(
        win32netcon.RESOURCETYPE_DISK,
        None, location.encode('utf8'), None,
        None, None)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\eclipseworkspaces\training\pytraining\win32networkstuff\unc.py",
line 66, in ?
    None, None)
pywintypes.error: (53, 'WNetAddConnection2', 'The network path was not found.')
```

What is the right way to handle this case?
Your help is highly appreciated.

I am running Python 2.6

Comment: If `pywin32` is calling `WNetAddConnection2A` internally, then the only way to get it to work would be to change your system default for non-Unicode strings to the Marathi(?) language and encode `mcbs`.  Alternatively, look into `ctypes` and call `WNetAddConnection2W` instead, so you can pass it Unicode strings.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set default encoding this way:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. 

MSDN WNetAddConnection2() API says use  WNetAddConnection2W() for unicode But python win32wnet module does not have WNetAddConnection2W() API

Do you know how to handle this instated of setting encoding default to 'utf-8' ?

Comment: No, you should use `WNetAddConnection2`. Check [first example here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/62730/win32wnet.NETRESOURCE). Why don't you use some SMB library (like [PySMB](http://pysmb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))?

Comment: Nope. I am not planning to use PySMB in my application. Will take look of this later. For Now Is there way to handle unicode share name with win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2()

Mentioned solution sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') is not working

Comment: [why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code](https://anonbadger.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/why-sys-setdefaultencoding-will-break-code/)